# Does Miscrosoft Kinect SDK provide any API that I can input detph image then return skeleton?

Tags: kinect, kinect-sdk

I need a help about how to get skeleton data from my modified Depth Image using KinectSDK.

I have two Kinect. And I can get the DepthImage from both of them. I transform the two Depth Image into a 3D-coordinate and combine them together by using OpenGL. Finally, I reproject the 3D scene and get a new DepthImage. (The resolution is also 640*480, and the FPS of my new DepthImage is about 20FPS)

Now, I want to get the skeleton from this new DepthImage by using KinectSDK.

Anyone can help me about this?

Thanks

This picture is my flow path:
[image]

Comment: No, the SDK can not do this.

Answer (score 2):

> Does Miscrosoft Kinect SDK provide any API that I can input detph image then return skeleton?

**No**.

I tried to find some libraries (not made by Microsoft) to accomplish this task, but it is not simple at all.

Try to follow [this discussion on ResearchGate](https://www.researchgate.net/post/Is_there_any_library_to_obtain_skeletal_joints_from_a_single_depth_image), there are some useful links (such as databases or early stage projects) from where you can start if you want to develop your library and share it with us.

Answer (score 0):

I was hoping to do something similar, feed post-processed depth image back to Kinect for skeleton segmentation, but unfortunately there doesn't seem to be a way of doing this with existing API.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you reconstruct a skeleton based upon your 3d depth data ?
The kinect Sdk can record a skeleton directly without such reconstruction.
And one camera is enough to record a skeleton.

if you use the kinect v2, then out of my head i can track 3 or 4 skeletons or so.

kinect provides basically 3 streams, rgb video, depth, skeleton.